# Why do we need to send JWT from client for every API after login, as DRF maintains isAuthenticated Flag after login in settings.py?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt

I have just started to explore django. I want to know whether JWT should be verified for every view manually in the server side or is there any better way of doing it.

**Login View:**

```
class LoginUser(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)            
            return Response({
                'response_code':'success',
                'response_msg':'Login successfull',
                'username':user.username,
                'token': jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY)
                },status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(
              {'response_code':'error',
                'response_msg':'Invalid credentials'},status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

**Menu View** (to fetch menu)

```
def getMenu(request):
    menu_list = serializers.serialize("json", Menu.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(menu_list)
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

My Login View returns JWT token in response. Login view works fine, but post login if I want to fetch Food Menu without sending JWT(got in response of login view), i am able to get the menu list, but ideally it should fail, saying Token is missing and should not return the response, but i am getting response.

I am curious to know, if DRF is only checking whether user is Authenticated or not and based on that if it returns response, then what is the point of JWT.

Answer (score 1):

Your menu view looks like a normal django view. You have to use a [DRF view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/)
since you've only configured authentication and permission for DRF.

Comment: @heygugo it is working as expected now. You saved my day.